# adding force directed algorithm to Raphael SVG objects

Tags: svg, raphael, d3.js

I am building a user interface using Raphael JS.  currently I have a `.js` script that draws out everything using Raphael JS 2.1 exactly as needed.  However, because the drawing is driven by dynamic data it is highly likely that objects will overlap. Adding the d3.js Force Layout to the objects would cause them to scatter automatically so there is no overlap of various ux components.  However I have not been able to apply the d3.js Force Layout to Raphael drawn SVG objects.

I've created a basic example using JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/brockness/pagHh/).  I used the [d3.js collision detection example](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/collision.html) as a "template".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've fixed up your example and posted the result at http://jsfiddle.net/gn6tZ/6/.  You had a minor typo in your collide function (`- y` instead of `- r`) and when you want to update the nodes after the force layout runs you need to supply the update function with the new data.

```
var nodes = circleHolder.nodes();

force.on("tick", function(e){
  var q = d3.geom.quadtree( nodes ),
      i = 0,
      n = nodes.length;

  while( ++i < n ) {
    q.visit(collide( nodes[i]));
  }

  d3.selectAll('circle')
       .data(nodes)
       .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
       .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

});
```

Comment: Any idea how could I adapt this example to create a forced layout between groups of shapes ? Let's say that a group is made of a rectangle shape and a text shape.

Answer (score -1):

[d3](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/)

One of the examples: [Force-Directed Graph](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/force.html)

Comment: from what i know of Raphael and what i see in that example i don't see how i can adapt what i have to work with d3.  can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can do the drawing with Raphael and let d3 take over from there. Unfotunatelly I'm not good at either of them :( . Are you limited to using Raphael?

Comment: i've already written a script that does everything i need.  at this point i just want to add a force directed algorithm so that my Raphael objects don't overlap