# Words overlap in d3-cloud

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js, d3-cloud

I'm trying to use d3 and d3-cloud to display a keyword cloud. It works, but my only problem is that the words overlap, And I dont understand why. I think it comes from the fontSize, but I can't find what exactly. [screen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/455rk.png)

Below are my different methods :

```
    private _populate(keyword: any) {
        const dataset = kw.map(function (d: any) { return { text: d.text, size: d.value }; });
        console.log(dataset);

        d3.layout.cloud()
            .size([this._width, this._height])
            .words(dataset)
            .padding(1)
            .rotate(0)
            .fontSize((d: any) => d.size / 100)
            .on('end', () => {
                this._drawWordCloud(dataset);
            })
            .start();
    }

    private _drawWordCloud(words: any) {
        this._svg
            .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + this._width / 2 + "," + this._height / 2 + ")")
                .selectAll("text")
                .data(words)
                .enter().append("text")
                    .style("font-size", (d: any) => d.size + "px")
                    .style("fill", "#69b3a2")
                    .style("font-family", "Impact")
                    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                    .attr("transform", (d: any) => "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")rotate(" + d.rotate + ")")
                    .text((d: any) => d.text);
    }
```

.fontSize((d: any) => d.size / 100) because my values are very high (~ 10000).

Someone can help me ? The various solutions (very few) that I have found do not work.

Thanks !

Comment: Can you use the D3 Force Directed Algorithm to prevent overlap? https://stackoverflow.com/a/10465974/773322

Comment: @b_dubb Thank you for your answer, I finally found the solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. You have to add the font you want to use in the first method "_populate". In my case :

```
.font("Impact")
```

And we don't change the line in the second method :

```
.style("font-family", "Impact")
```

That's all ! I hope it can help other people